# Who is this person who climbs Mt. Tsukuba and also Mt. McKinley?

Tags: noukome

In episode 1 of **Ore no nounai sentakushi ga, Gakuen Love-comedy wo Zenryoku de Jama shiteiru** (or **NouKome** or **NouCome** or whatever else you want to call it), as part of the hilarious montage of people making choices throughout history, there's a mountain climber:

[image: A mountain climber faced with two choices]

His first choice is "Climb Mt. McKinley", and his second choice is "Be satisfied with Mt. Tsukuba". He is shown as selecting the first choice, and then, presumably upon reaching the summit of Mt. McKinley, shouting "Naomi!".

Who is he supposed to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely to be a reference to [Naomi Uemura](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naomi_Uemura), the first person ever to climb Mt. McKinley solo.

As a side note, Mt. Tsukuba is 877 meters high at it's highest peak), while Mt. McKinley is 6,194 meters high at it's highest peak.